# Delete constrained 2048px images and upload "high quality" < 16MP photos

Tags: photos, google-photos

I'm attempting to delete my constrained 2048px images off of google photos to make way for the new less than 16MP photos "high quality" version of the photos.

My concern is that by deleting the photos off of Google Photos, I will delete my original quality local versions (I have taken backups).

I have tried:

- Turning off sync on  (local copies still removed when deleting from Photos)
- Copying photos to new directory, and uploading (doesn't upload new copy, I suspect their dupe checking is via date/time)

Has anyone successfully removed their lower quality images, and re-uploaded the originals at the higher quality successfully?

Comment: This article should show you exactly how to reclaim space by compressing "Original Quality" images down to "High Quality":
https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6314648?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This feature was added after I originally logged this, but it'd be good for future people looking for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so I think I've roughly worked out the process, please feel free to comment, or correct if you find this is inaccurate:

It appears that deleting from google photos (at least on my Galaxy S5, and Tab 3) does *not* delete the original. My photos are held on the external SD card on both devices. Not sure whether this matters. Having deleted the photos on the web, I can still see the originals in my camera folder. I'd be **extremely** cautious attempting this test on a stock Android phone as it may be different.

What deleting *does* do, is it seems to retain the record of the file on their server. So even when I cleared app data after deleting the photos, and backing up again, the photos did not back up.

Now what I have found useful, is that despite this shortcoming on Android (may be a workaround somehow, perhaps going a step further and deleting the app?), **I can import the previously deleted photos onto a computer, and upload via the Photo Backup service, or manually via the web app.**

I think it's theoretically plausible that I could delete all my smaller photos uploaded previously and re-upload without issue, but I think I'm going to do them slowly and carefully.

I wish Google would provide a bit more insight into how Photos checks that a photo has been previously uploaded (and perhaps deleted) but I hope this is helpful.